# Find closest date within group

Tags: python, pandas

I am at a loss at how to proceed with the following problem: I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        "type": ["B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"],
        "date": pd.to_datetime(
            ["1/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "2/1/2020"]
        ),
    }
)

print(df)
```

```
   id type       date
0   1    B 2020-01-01
1   1    A 2020-07-01
2   1    B 2020-08-01
3   1    B 2020-12-01
4   2    A 2020-02-01
5   2    B 2020-02-01
```

Within one `id` there is one element of type `A` and several of type `B`. Now I would like to arrive at a frame where within one `id` I want to find the pair of types `A` and `B`, with the closest dates.

For the above example this would be:

```
id         A           B    delta_t
1   7/1/2020    8/1/2020         31
2   2/1/2020    2/1/2020          0
```

I have tried going through un-melting the dataframe with `pivot` as an intermediate first step, but that only works if there is only one `A` and `B`type per `id`-group.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        "type": ["B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"],
        "date": pd.to_datetime(
            #im assuming the 2nd date here is supposed to be "7/1/2020", not "7/1/2000" as you've given.
            ["1/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "2/1/2020"] 
        ),
    }
)
print(df)
```

The simplest approach i can think of is simply segregating the dataframe into two separate dataframes, and using a merge to align the dates. Note that this heavily relies on your statement that "Within one id there is one element of type A". With the dataframes segregated and merged on id in this manner, the rest is just calculating the time delta, and then taking the value with the smallest timedelta in each id using a groupby.

```
df_type_a = df[df["type"] == 'A']
df_type_b = df[df["type"] == 'B']
merged = df_type_b.merge(df_type_a, on="id", suffixes = ('_B', '_A'))
merged['delta_t'] = (merged['date_B'] - merged['date_A']).abs()
#sort values to get the minimum delta values on top,
#then groupby on id and take the first in each group
out = merged.sort_values('delta_t').groupby('id').first()
#reset indexes if you want id back as a column
print(out.reset_index())
#Output:
   id type_B     date_B type_A     date_A delta_t
0   1      B 2020-08-01      A 2020-07-01 31 days
1   2      B 2020-02-01      A 2020-02-01  0 days
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I was somehow stuck with the idea to do everything in one dataframe. Separating it into two is a very clever approach.

Answer (score 2):

Another method using `groupby` with `abs` and `idxmin` to obtain the closest dates of B, then `join` back to the original dataframe:

```
x = lambda d: d.loc[(d.loc[d["type"].eq("A"),"date"].iat[0]-
                     d.loc[d["type"].eq("B"),"date"]).abs().idxmin()]

result = (df.loc[df["type"].eq("A")].set_index("id").rename(columns={"type":"type_A","date":"date_A"})
            .join(df.groupby("id").apply(x).drop("id",1).rename(columns={"type":"type_B","date":"date_B"})))

result["delta_t"] = result["date_B"]-result["date_A"]

print (result)

   type_A     date_A type_B     date_B delta_t
id
1       A 2020-07-01      B 2020-08-01 31 days
2       A 2020-02-01      B 2020-02-01  0 days
```